# FileStream with DeleteOnClose File option

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

In my project I have to create some temp files in an USB device, which I want to delete on Closing. So I used a code like

```
this.fcommandHandler = new FileStream(TempFileName,
FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
FileShare.ReadWrite, 512, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
```

It works fine. But the problem is I want to use one more FileOption, like No buffering.

```
private const FileOptions FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = (FileOptions)0x20000000;

this.fcommandHandler = new FileStream(TempFileName,
FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
FileShare.ReadWrite, 512, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose & FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING);
```

But its not deleting the File after closing. Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `|` instead of `&`.

These are binary flags, and when you say `&`, you effectively mask them all away, resulting in no options at all.

Comment: But I am getting an exception "IO operation will not work. Most likely the file will become too long or the handle was not opened to support synchronous IO operations.", if I put | instead of &, when I am calling this.fcommandHandler.Close()

Comment: @Anuraj: That doesn't mean | is wrong, it means something in your usage is incorrect. Lasse is right that you need | instead of &. The exception is your next problem to solve.

Comment: @Jeff Yates: Thanks let my try with some other options.

Comment: How do I do this in VB.NET?  I am having a similar problem with `And` the result is 0

Comment: Try using `Or` instead, I'm not a VB expert though so if you're stuck you might want to search for it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` the `&` cancels them out.

`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING & FileOptions.DeleteOnClose` returns `FileOptions.None`

Comment: Please check the comment of the first answer.

Comment: @Anuraj: I'm trying to figure out what the File_flag_no_buffering is, the DeleteOnClose is definitely not getting called because you're doing an and instead of an or.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich - The File_flag_no_buffering file option is a file option, which helps to avoid file caching when reading and writing files, by Windows. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122362/how-to-empty-flush-windows-read-disk-cache-in-c

Comment: @Anuraj: Thank you. You can see the | being applied in the answers on that thread.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich:I am getting an exception "IO operation will not work. Most likely the file will become too long or the handle was not opened to support synchronous IO operations.", if I put | instead of &, when I am calling this.fcommandHandler.Close()

Answer (score 0):

Try including the `WriteThrough` flag as well in a list using the | operator.  See this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99794) on the requirements for using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`.  Its interesting that MS hasn't included this flag in the enum.  Is there a reason why `WriteThrough` doesn't do what you need in this scenario?  You are trying to write secure data?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I tried this but still I am getting this error. I am trying achieve is like : I have to issue some commands to a USB via a File(ex. cmd.bin) device, and it will return some responses in a File(ex. res.bin). But if I use normal C# Stream Windows will cache the response and always I will get the same response, so I have to use the No Buffering flag. And the files are temporary so I have to delete it after use;thats why I am using Delete On close flag.

Comment: In that case the question that Yuriy has directed to you has a different approach to opening such a file, I'd give that a go.