# how to improve a large number of smaller files read and write speed or performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, io, filesystems

Yesterday,I asked the question at here:[how do disable disk cache in c# invoke win32 CreateFile api with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692635/how-do-disable-disk-cache-in-c-sharp-invoke-win32-createfile-api-with-file-flag).

In my performance test show(write and read test,1000 files and total size 220M),the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` can't help me improve performance and lower than .net default disk cache,since i try change `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`  to `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` can to reach the .net default disk cache and faster little.

before,i try use mongodb's gridfs feature replace the windows file system，not good(and i don't need to use distributed feature,just taste).

in my Product,the server can get a lot of the smaller files(60-100k) on per seconds through tcp/ip,then need save it to the disk,and third service read these files once(just read once and process).if i use asynchronous I/O whether can help me,whether can get best speed and best low cpu cycle?. someone can give me suggestion?or i can still use FileStream class?

**update 1**

the **memory mapped file** whether can to achieve my demand.that all files write to one big file or more and read from it?

Comment: Is it really necessary to write these files to disk, if you just process them once?

Comment: Just go to your questions and mark the answered which helped you achieving your task by checking the "right arrow" next to anwes ... :-)

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay,thanks,i solved it.i will note.

Comment: It's pretty clear from your comment to Tigran's post that you are trying to solve the wrong problem.  You'll have to throttle the clients, preventing them from uploading files at a rate higher then you can ever process.  If that's not acceptable then you'll need to throw hardware at the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your PC is taking 5-10 seconds to write a 100kB file to disk, then you either have the world's oldest, slowest PC, or your code is doing something very inefficient.

Turning off disk caching will probably make things worse rather than better. With a disk cache in place, your writes will be fast, and Windows will do the slow part of flushing the data to disk later. Indeed, increasing I/O buffering usually results in significantly improved I/O in general.

You definitely want to use asynchronous writes - that means your server starts the data writing, and then goes back to responding to its clients while the OS deals with writing the data to disk in the background.

There shouldn't be any need to queue the writes (as the OS will already be doing that if disc caching is enabled), but that is something you could try if all else fails - it could potentially help by writing only one file at a time to minimise the need for disk seeks..

Generally for I/O, using larger buffers helps to increase your throughput. For example instead of writing each individual byte to the file in a loop, write a buffer-ful of data (ideally the entire file, for the sizes you mentioned) in one Write operation. This will minimise the overhead (instead of calling a write function for every byte, you call a function once for the entire file). I suspect you may be doing something like this, as it's the only way I know to reduce performance to the levels you've suggested you are getting.

Memory-mapped files will not help you. They're really best for accessing the contents of huge files.

Comment: hi,@Jason Williams,thanks for your suggest. it let me clear how to do,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of buggest and significant improvements, in your case, can be, imo, process the filles *without* saving them to a disk and after, if you really need to store them, push them on `Queue` and provess it in another thread, by saving them on disk. By doing this you will immidiately get processed data you need, without losing time to save a data on disk, but also will have a file on disk after, without losing computational power of your  `file processor`.

Comment: hi,@Tigran,before i also consider use Queue.but,the client send 20-30 files on second in multi-thread,and server process one file need elapsed 5-10 seconds,if a lot of files keep in memory,will throw memoryleak exception.

Comment: From one place you can load into `queue` from another thread save to disk and remove from queue. Do not populate ALL and after process it, but process during the run.