# Direct un-buffered writes in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Currently I am trying to run a test that will power-down the machine abruptly when a file is being written. When power-down occurs the last part of data is not present as it is never flushed to disk before power down.

Perl (in Linux) allows direct un-buffered writes when a file is opened in the following manner.

```
sysopen(F, $file, O_WRONLY|O_DIRECT) or die "Couldn't direct open file $file\n";
```

This allows data to be written till the last character in-case machine crashes due to some reason. Likewise, for windows, C++ allows direct writes when a file is opened for writes using "FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING" flag.

How can I allow direct/un-buffered writes to disk using powershell ?

Answer (score 1):

You could drop down to .NET and use a FileStream object to write the file. Use the constructor that takes FileOptions and [try the FileOptions.WriteThrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122362/how-to-empty-flush-windows-read-disk-cache-in-c) enum value, e.g.:

```
$fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($file,
    [System.IO.FileMode]::Create, 
    [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify,
    [System.IO.FileShare]::None,
    1,
    [System.IO.FileOptions]::WriteThrough)
```

Comment: An example: `$fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($file, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create, [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify, [System.IO.FileShare]::None, 1, [System.IO.FileOptions]::WriteThrough)`. I don't feel confident enough to edit a 32.8k user's answer!

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie Bah, go for it.  :-)  The unfortunate downside of answering questions on a tablet is that it's painful to provide lengthy answers.  :-(